# How can I embed my YouTube channel? It has an irregular name

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

How can I embed my YouTube channel? It has an irregular name.

So, you might think it's easy. But I have tried for hours already, please bear that in mind before dismissing this question.

Here is the link to the channel, it has an irregular name for some reason "UCdEti36s42cHELTpCroPGVA" which does not correspond to what I have actually chosen.

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCdEti36s42cHELTpCroPGVA/videos?sort=dd&shelf_id=0&view=0

I simply want to embed the whole channel in an HTML page.

So today's date is the 8th of February 2017. I am looking for a solution that actually works today so please do not refer to some old google links that may have worked in 2012. Also solutions that work for channels with regular names do not necessarily work for channels with irregular URI schemes.

Vesa

I have tried this already and a lot of other snippets and so on (pseudocode):

Iframe - User_upload - Yourchannelname

Answer (score 0):

1. find your video on youtube site
2. go to share button below on video
3. Ahead of the link shown click on "Embed" button.
4. Do copy-paste iframe code into your HTML web page.